# unable to get info on the jython interpreter error on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jython-2.7

I am trying to add Jython interpreter and I am getting this error. It shows unable to get info on the interpreter. python and jython require at least version 2.1 and ironpython 2.6
[image: error]

does anybody know the solution ? please let me know. I am using "Eclipse Luna"

Comment: Do You configure Jython interpreter in PyDev? Try install Jython from Homebrew

Comment: I tried to install from Homebrew but still getting same error - this is my location of the jar

/Users/afre/Downloads/homebrew/Cellar/jython/2.5.3/libexec/jython.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try install the stable version 2.5.4

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.5.4-rc1/jython-installer-2.5.4-rc1.jar