# Error while configuring python with eclipse pydev plugin on WIndows

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Earlier, couple of times, I have successfully installed and configured python with eclipse PyDev plugin on 64 bit Windows 7. Now I have to do the same on another 32 bit Windows 7 system. Biggest hurdle is that I don't have admin privileges on this system (the same was the case in earlier installations).

I have installed WinPython-32bit-3.5.4.1Qt5. I have added installation directory and script folder location (`D:\Programs\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.5.4.1Qt5;D:\Programs\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.5.4.1Qt5\scripts;`) to path user environment variable.

Now when I run `python` in command prompt, it gives me following error:
[image]

Quick googling tells that this has [something to do with installation of Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2017](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/python-360-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt/a58999ec-a94e-44ad-8f92-8136ce98871b?auth=1). As far as I remember, I dont have to do this last time.

Next in eclipse Neon 4.6.0, I installed PyDev for Eclipse 6.2.0.201711281614 plugin.

Inside Eclipse, at `Windows > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter`, I tried to specify the python interpreter, but I get following error:

[image]

I [didnt find much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985076/unable-to-get-info-on-the-jython-interpreter-error-on-eclipse) on this error. In fact I dont understand what error is trying to tell.

What I am missing here? Why I am facing difficulties while setting up python on Windows even when I am following same steps as last time?

Answer (score 0):

For configuring eclipse with pydev plugin you just only need to do these steps ,
Go To `windows->preferences->python interpreter->select path of your python interpreter`

Now in your case these error basically occurs because of your microsoft visual c++ 2015 distribution . You should do these steps as described in video by "Maddy" ,

[fixing of api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj4ui1R1LIs) .
Or you can use these [directly download required dll file and place in computer](https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.html)